# Installing ZeligMultilevel. Error : object ‘describe’ is not exported by 'namespace:Zelig'

Tags: r, r-zelig

I am trying to use ZeligMultilevel but I am having problems when opening the library. Please, see below:

```
> install.packages("ZeligMultilevel")
```

> trying URL
>   'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/ZeligMultilevel_0.7-1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 267971 bytes (261 KB) downloaded
>   261 KB
>
> package ‘ZeligMultilevel’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkHO9ls\downloaded_packages

```
> library(ZeligMultilevel)
```

> Error : object ‘describe’ is not exported by 'namespace:Zelig'
>
> Error:package or namespace load failed for ‘ZeligMultilevel’

I already tried installing it with dependencies=TRUE. I also tried installing ZeligMultilevel from the source and I have the same problem. I think there must be a tiny silly thing that I am missing, but I cannot find what to do...

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a compatibility problem between the latest version of the `Zelig` package and `ZeligMultilevel`. Notice that the latest version of Zelig was uploaded about a week ago.

Try downloading an older version of Zelig and installing that.
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Zelig/

Installing the `Zelig_4.2-1.tar.gz` from the 21-Sep-2013 worked for me.