# ZeligMultilevel R v3.2.4 not available

Tags: r, r-zelig

I searched for this topic but didn't find any posts. If there's already a post, sorry about the double post!

I tried to install `ZeligMultilevel` but my R version (3.2.4) is too new.

Is there still a way to install `ZeligMultilevel` on 3.2.4? If yes, how can I do it?

Or do I have to downgrade my R in order to install `ZeligMultilevel`? If yes, which R version does run `ZeligMultilevel`?

Thank you for your support! :-)

Comment: [This SO question might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867786/installing-zeligmultilevel-error-object-describe-is-not-exported-by-namesp).

Comment: Can you please show the actual error message? Saying that your version is too new sounds like an assumption. Usually packages built on older versions of R still work on newer versions.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
the actual error message:

> install.packages("ZeligMultilevel")
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'ZeligMultilevel' is not available (for R version 3.2.4)

I don't think i did any typingerrors. 
I also installed Zelig packages. This works fine but the ZeligMulitlevel doesnt.

Comment: I've found this link very useful to deal with such problems:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa?rq=1